# What is the optimal system configuration required for doing data analysis in R

Tags: r

Original dataset is ~0.75 million rows with 7 variables. After some basic feature engineering, it became 81 int variables. In order for easy manipulation during initial stages, I chose to take just 0.01% as my training set using the below script

```
sub <- sample(nrow(d), floor(nrow(d) * 0.01))
train <- d[sub, ]
test <- d[-sub, ]
```

To build an initial model was trying to do dimension reduction / PCA on this training dataset.

```
require(leaps)
require(MASS)

initialBasicSubSet <- regsubsets(myVariable ~ ., data = train, nvmax = 25, really.big=T)
```

The problem is this code seems to run forever. As of now it has been running for more than 9 hrs! Since I am pretty new to R & data analysis want to know whether this is something abnormal (considering there is only ~7000 records with 81 int variables)?

Below is the configuration of my laptop and wanted to know from people who are doing data analysis using R on whether this suffices or is there any other specific configuration should I upgrade to?

System Configuration:

```
HP Pavilion dv6 Notebook PC
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz
8 GB RAM
64 bit OS - Windows 7 Home Premium
```

Comment: What's wrong with you guys? Why do you keep downvoting even for genuine questions? Aren't people who are learning not supposed to ask questions here??

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I can see why people would consider this question (1) not useful (it mistakes a fundamental difficulty of problem scale for a computational configuration issue) and (2) poorly researched (arguably this kind of back-of-the-envelope calculation should be done *before* you start running code ...)

Comment: Prasanth, you may want to use a tool that monitors RAM and swap usage, along with CPU usage.  There's probably something included in Windows 7.  Given Ben Bolker's answer, I doubt that insufficient RAM is the problem, but it's worth monitoring.  Some operations in R can use a lot of RAM with a moderate amount of data.  8GB hasn't always been enough for me.  I've had to rewrite my code or find another computer.

Comment: @Mars Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your computer configuration is not the problem.

As far as I can see, you have chosen (since the default argument is `method="exhaustive"`) to do **exhaustive** evaluation of all 25-variable subsets of 81 possible variables , which gives you this many models to evaluate:

```
choose(81,25)  ## [1] 5.25652e+20
```

If you can evaluate 1000 models per second this will take

```
log10(choose(81,25)/(365*24*3600*1000))  ## 10.22 ...
```

approximately 10^10 years to complete.

You could try something like `method="forward"`.  Alternatively, I have had good luck with the [glmulti](https://cran.r-project.org/package=glmulti) package:

> Automated model selection and model-averaging.
>                         Provides a wrapper for glm and other functions,
>                         automatically generating all possible models
>                         (under constraints set by the user) with the
>                         specified response and explanatory variables, and
>                         finding the best models in terms of some
>                         Information Criterion (AIC, AICc or BIC). Can
>                         handle very large numbers of candidate models.
>                         Features a Genetic Algorithm to find the best
>                         models when an exhaustive screening of the
>                         candidates is not feasible.

Or use PCA, or the `glmnet` package, or random forests, or ...

Comment: thanks for your response. I did try method = "forward" it gave out a warning "18  linear dependencies found" but when I tried printing initialBasicSubSet it didn't show me the usual what is the 1 or 2 .. 25 combinations i can choose from.

Comment: Does http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44358/regsubsets-with-leaps-fails help?